# Динамическое изменение кастомного атрибута элемента

Tags: javascript

Коллеги, пытаюсь передать `input.value` кастомнуму атрибуту `d`.
Но получаю два разных поведения.

В первом варианте все вроде бы работает, но атрибуту `d` остается пустой

Во-втором варианте не получаю ничего, но у атрибуту `d` меняется значение

Насколько я помню, оба варианта должны иметь одинаковый результат

```js
const in1 = document.querySelector('#input-1'),
  in2 = document.querySelector('#input-2');

in1.addEventListener('input', () => {
  in1.d = in1.value;
  console.clear();
  console.log(in1, typeof in1);
  document.querySelector('.info-1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(in1.d) + '--' + JSON.stringify(in1);
})


in2.addEventListener('input', () => {
  in2.setAttribute('d', in2.value);
  console.clear();
  console.log(in2, typeof in1)
  document.querySelector('.info-2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(in2.d) + '--' + JSON.stringify(in2);
})
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div>Вариант раз</div>
  <input id="input-1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" d>
  <div class="info-1">info</div>
</div>
<div class="conteiner">
  <div>Вариант два</div>
  <input id="input-2" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" d>
  <div class="info-2">info</div>
</div>
```

В итоге, я хочу получить такое поведение, чтобы и значение атрибута изменялось и блок `info` не был пустым

Comment: Свойства != Атрибуты. Да, некоторые стандартные атрибуты и свойства являются синонимами и зависимы. Но, для кастомных такое поведение не гарантируется.

Comment: Кастомные атрибуты должны начинаться с префикса `data-`, тогда будет работать в обоих случаях

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, `html-5` по новому стандарту приставка `data-` не обязательна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта:

- одновременная установка свойства и атрибута;
- использование dataset.

Я за первый вариант, как за самый простой, понятный и надёжный:

```js
const in1 = document.querySelector('#input-1'),
  in2 = document.querySelector('#input-2');

/* ------ Вариант раз ------- */
in1.addEventListener('input', () => {
  in1.d = in1.value;
  in1.setAttribute('d', in1.d);
  console.clear();
  console.log(in1, typeof in1);
  document.querySelector('.info-1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(in1.d) + '--' + JSON.stringify(in1);
})

/* ------ Вариант два ------- */
in2.addEventListener('input', () => {
  in2.setAttribute('data-d', in2.value);
  //in2.dataset.d = in2.value;
  console.clear();
  console.log(in2, typeof in2)
  document.querySelector('.info-2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(in2.dataset.d) + '--' + JSON.stringify(in2.dataset);
  //document.querySelector('.info-2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(in2.getAttribute('data-d')) + '--' + JSON.stringify(in2.dataset);
})
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div>Вариант раз</div>
  <input id="input-1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <div class="info-1">info</div>
</div>
<div class="conteiner">
  <div>Вариант два</div>
  <input id="input-2" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <div class="info-2">info</div>
</div>
```